# Prove using Jensen's Inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, inequality, problem-solving

Let $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, . . . , \alpha_n$ be the interior angles of a convex (but not necessarily regular) n-gon. Prove, that for all integers $n\geq3$:

$$\cos \alpha_1 + \cos \alpha_2 +  \cdots  + \cos \alpha_n + n \cos\left(\dfrac{2\pi}{n}\right) \leq0$$

The prof said that I need to use Jensen's Inequality, and may be something else.. But I don't see it!

Comment: Perhaps the last $+$ should be a $-$ ?

Comment: @leonbloy All are $+$ noting negative!

Comment: @leonbloy Doesn't help, for a quadrilateral that term is zero.

Comment: @Macavity With one angle larger than $\pi$ the polygon is not convex.

Comment: There seems to be also a missing factor inside the last cosine. Check it

Comment: @Dirk Thanks. But check with one angle $\frac{4\pi}5$ and the others equal then.  I still get positive LHS.

Comment: I see Jensen being applicable if all interior angles are given to be acute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all the interior angles are acute, then noting that $\cos \theta$ is concave for $\theta \in (0, {\pi \over 2})$, we can use Jensen's Inequality.

$$\frac1n \sum \cos \alpha_i \le \cos \left(\frac1n \sum \alpha_i \right) = \cos \left( \frac{\pi(n-2)}{n} \right) = \cos(\pi - \frac{2\pi}{n}) = -\cos(\frac{2\pi}n)$$

Note that this is more restrictive than just being convex, and in fact your inequality does *not* hold in general if one of the angles can be larger than $\pi \over 2$.

Comment: this Jensen's inequality is weird (different, let's say!)

Comment: What happened to the last term?

Comment: Well, I quite like it, it's useful in many cases especially when you have concave or convex functions...

Comment: Check, the last term is the RHS, in negative form.

Comment: ohh... I see... Definitely I got to read more an understand better Jensen's. It hard to apply it out of the blue without knowing the basis. THX!

Comment: how did you get $cos(\dfrac{\pi(n-2)}{n})$?

Comment: The numerator of that is the sum of all interior angles in a polygon. An easy way to get it is to consider walking along the boundary, turning at each exterior angle. You complete one rotation, I.e sum of all exterior angles in a polygon is $2\pi$.